# There is an PowerShell script, I just want the output should be stored in the CSV format

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have one powershell script, this script is supposed to execute on Domain controller. The script which is executed from Domain Controller server will fetch all the member server details and will remotely execute the script on all the member servers. The script will modify existing firewall with ports mentioned below and restrict access to those ports from outside the networks defined. Script will be setting the IP range from which the ports can be accessed. Here are the Windows  firewall ports that will have the access restriction after executing the script. I just want to save how many nodes the execution got passed and how many nodes it got failed and failure log. These things needs to be stored in CSV file.

I have attached my script below.

I am looking forward to hear from you.

```
clear
write-host "`n`n`n==============================================================================="
write-host "============This script is to only allow specific subnet to particular ports ====================" -fore Green
write-host "NOTE: Before run the script make sure all the servers are UP, Reachable & WinRM Connectivity is fine" -fore Yellow
write-host "===============================================================================`n`n"

########## Port numbers to restrict access

$ports=@(22,53,88,135,136,137,138,139,389,445,1801,1433,3389,5985,5986,5671,5672,8080)
$IPsubnets = @("63.145.62.0/25")

function configure-firewall($IPsubnets,$ports)
{
    [array]$Script:CurrentRules = Get-NetFirewallRule

    foreach($port in $ports)
    {

        if(! (Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | Where-Object -Property LocalPort -EQ $port))
        {
            write-host "firewall rule not exists for port : $port. creating"
            try
            {
                New-NetFirewallRule -Group 'Philips' -Action Allow -LocalPort $port -Direction inbound -Protocol TCP -DisplayName 'PerimeterSecurity'
            }
            catch
            {
                write-host "Error while setting rule: $($Error[0].Exception)"
            }
        }
        # write-host "executing for port : $port"
        Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | Where-Object -Property LocalPort -EQ $port | Get-NetFirewallRule | Where-Object -property Direction -EQ inbound| Where-Object -Property Enabled -eq True | Set-NetFirewallRule -Action Allow -RemoteAddress $($IPsubnets)
    }
}

while($True)
{
    $IPsubnet =Read-host "Enter IP subnet Range  (example - 172.16.20.0/24)  "
    $status = [bool]($IPsubnet.split('/')[0] -as [ipaddress])
    
    if ($status) 
    {
        $IPsubnets += $IPsubnet
        #write-host "IP subnet array : $IPsubnets"
        $input = Read-Host "Do you want to add another Subnet ? (y/n)"
        if ($input -eq 'n')
        {
            break
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "`n$IPsubnet is not a Valid IP Address.. Enter Valid IP Address" -fore Red
    }
}


# get member servers
try
{
    $memberServers=Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties ipv4Address 
}
catch 
{
    write-host "This is not a Domain controller. So firewall settings will be applied only to the local host"
    $memberServers = @{name = hostname}
}


foreach ($memberServer in $memberServers)
{
    try
    {
        write-host "Executing on" $memberServer.name -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $er="__"
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $memberServer.name -ScriptBlock ${function:configure-firewall} -ArgumentList $IPsubnets, $ports -ErrorVariable er -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if($er.count -eq 0)
        {
        write-host "Successfully executed on" $memberServer.name -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        else
        {
        $len=$erroe.count
        write-host "Below error found on  " $memberServer.name -ForegroundColor red
        write-host " Error found : -  $er" -Backgroundcolor Red
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        $len=$erroe.count
        write-host " Error found - $error[$len-1]" -Backgroundcolor Red
    }
    
}
```

Comment: @mklement0 Hi Klement - Oh I got it. I am sorry for tagged you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
$filename = 'c:\temp\errors.csv'
$table =  [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach ($memberServer in $memberServers)
{
    
    try
    {
        write-host "Executing on" $memberServer.name -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $er="__"
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $memberServer.name -ScriptBlock ${function:configure-firewall} -ArgumentList $IPsubnets, $ports -ErrorVariable er -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if($er.count -eq 0)
        {
           write-host "Successfully executed on" $memberServer.name -ForegroundColor Green
           $newRow = [psobject]@{ 
              'Member Server' = $memberServer.name
              Error='None'
           }
        }
        else
        {
           $len=$erroe.count
           write-host "Below error found on  " $memberServer.name -ForegroundColor red
           write-host " Error found : -  $er" -Backgroundcolor Red
           $newRow = [psobject]@{ 
              'Member Server' = $memberServer.name
              Error= $er
              Count=$len
           }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        $len=$erroe.count
        write-host " Error found - $error[$len-1]" -Backgroundcolor Red
        $newRow = [psobject]@{ 
              'Member Server' = $memberServer.name
              Error= $error[$len-1]
              Count=$len
        }

    }
    $table.Add($newRow)
}
$table | Export-CSV -Path $filename
```

Comment: Marked your answer as right answer.